# Incrementing HashMap values for key frequency doesn't print

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, frequency

I am currently working on a project to count the frequency of words in a text file. The driver program places the words into an ArrayList (after making them lowercase and removing whitespace), and then the FreqCount object places the ArrayList into a HashMap that will handle the frequency operations. So far, I can get the driver to read the text file, put it into an ArrayList, and then put that into the HashMap. My issue is that the HashMap nodes do not repeat, so I am trying to increment the value each time the word is seen.

Driver:

```
package threetenProg3;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Driver {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        File in = new File("test.txt");
        Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(in);
        
        ArrayList<String> parsed = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        
        while(scanFile.hasNext()) { //if this ends up cutting off bottom line, make it a do while loop
            parsed.add(scanFile.next().toLowerCase());
        }
        
        for(int i = parsed.size()-1; i>=0; i--) { //prints arraylist backwards
            System.out.println(parsed.get(i));
        } //*/
        
        FreqCount fc = new FreqCount(parsed);
        
        System.out.println("\n Hashmap: \n");
        fc.printMap();
        
        scanFile.close();
        
    }
}
```

FreqCount:

```
package threetenProg3;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class FreqCount {
    //attributes and initializations
    private HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    
    //constructors
    
    FreqCount(List<String> driverList){
        for(int dLIndex = driverList.size()-1; dLIndex>=0; dLIndex--) { //puts list into hashmap
            
            for(String mapKey : map.keySet()) {
                
                if(mapKey.equals(driverList.get(dLIndex))) {
                    int tval = map.get(mapKey);
                    
                    map.remove(mapKey);
                    
                    map.put(mapKey, tval+1);
                }else {
                    map.put(mapKey, 1);
                }
                
            }
                
        }
        
    }
    
    //methods
    
    public void printMap() {
        for (String i : map.keySet()) { //function ripped straight outta w3schools lol
              System.out.println("key: " + i + " value: " + map.get(i));
        }
    } //*/
    
}
```

Text file:

```
ONE TWO ThReE FoUR fIve
six     seven        
EIGHT
     NINE       
TEN ELEVEN
ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE ONE, ONE, ONE,
```

Output:

```
one,
one,
one,
one
one
one
one
one
one
one
one
one
one
one
one
one
one
eleven
ten
nine
eight
seven
six
five
four
three
two
one

 Hashmap: 

key: nine value: 1
key: one, value: 1
key: six value: 1
key: four value: 1
key: one value: 1
key: seven value: 1
key: eleven value: 1
key: ten value: 1
key: five value: 1
key: three value: 1
key: two value: 1
key: eight value: 1
```

From what I see, the output should be printing the correct values for the keys' frequencies. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the definition of `FreqCount` as follows:

```
FreqCount(List<String> driverList) {
    for (int dLIndex = driverList.size() - 1; dLIndex >= 0; dLIndex--) {
        String key = driverList.get(dLIndex);
        if (map.get(key) == null) {
            map.put(key, 1);
        } else {
            map.put(key, map.get(key) + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output after this change:**

```
 Hashmap: 

key: nine value: 1
key: one, value: 3
key: six value: 1
key: four value: 1
key: one value: 15
key: seven value: 1
key: eleven value: 1
key: ten value: 1
key: five value: 1
key: three value: 1
key: two value: 1
key: eight value: 1
```

**Alternatively,**

```
FreqCount(List<String> driverList) {
    for (int dLIndex = driverList.size() - 1; dLIndex >= 0; dLIndex--) {
        String key = driverList.get(dLIndex);
        map.put(key, map.getOrDefault(key, 0) + 1);
    }
}
```

[`Map#getOrDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or default value if this map contains no mapping for the key.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need, but after retyping code into my eclipse it still prints all the values as 1. Even copy and pasting directly from here into the code produces the same results. To be clear this has happened for all of these fixes not just yours.

Comment: Nevermind! I assumed it was an eclipse problem and moved everything to a fresh project. It works now. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this, imo, is to use the [Map.merge](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method.  The method takes the previous value and applies a mapping function.  In this case the second value is unused. The first value is used to replace the existing value + 1.  Thus you are getting the frequency of the occurrence of the strings.

Also notice that I changed our class to use a `parse` method which returns the map.  It is not appropriate to do much computation in a class constructor.

After reading in the values.

```
         
FreqCount fc = new FreqCount();
Map<String,Integer> map = fc.parse(parsed);
        
map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
nine=1
one,=3
six=1
four=1
one=15
seven=1
eleven=1
ten=1
five=1
three=1
two=1
eight=1
```

The modified class

```
class FreqCount {
    // attributes and initializations
    private Map<String, Integer> map =
            new HashMap<>();
    
    public Map<String, Integer> parse (List<String> driverList) {
        for (String str : driverList) {
            map.merge(str, 1, (v1,notUsed)->v1 + 1);
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is part of the assignment that I cannot use those advanced map functions (sorry should've mentioned that). I got my answer but thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues there.

```
FreqCount(List<String> driverList){
    for(int dLIndex = driverList.size()-1; dLIndex>=0; dLIndex--) { //puts list into hashmap
        if(map.get(driverList.get(dLIndex)) != null) {
            int tval = map.get(driverList.get(dLIndex));
            map.remove(driverList.get(dLIndex));
            map.put(driverList.get(dLIndex), tval+1);
        }else {
            map.put(driverList.get(dLIndex), 1);
        }
    }

}
```

You are doing some weird for loop there trying to iterate through an empty Map. You need to check if there is a key to that word in the map, if there is you add one to the value and if there is not you add the new pair with value 1.

And to avoid the number with comas or dots(if you want you can add other characters to the regex that replaceAll takes as a parameter)

```
while(scanFile.hasNext()) { //if this ends up cutting off bottom line, make it a do while loop
        String value = scanFile.next().toLowerCase();
        value = value.replaceAll("[,.]", "");
        parsed.add(value);
    }
```

The output now is

```
one
one
one
one
one
one
one
one
one
one
one
one
one
one
one
one
one
eleven
ten
nine
eight
seven
six
five
four
three
two
one

 Hashmap: 

key: nine value: 1
key: six value: 1
key: four value: 1
key: one value: 18
key: seven value: 1
key: eleven value: 1
key: ten value: 1
key: five value: 1
key: three value: 1
key: two value: 1
key: eight value: 1
```

with no repetitions on the words even with comas and the correct count of each one

Comment: Thanks! I don't think we've covered regex yet so I will look into it more in depth to see if that's something my professor wants here.